# Primer for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I initially posted this on SO, but it got downvoted and vote to closed immediately, which I took as a sign I should move this here... If not, hopefully someone here will tell me where to ask the question...

I'm a software developer with 25 years experience building stand-alone applications. I'm trying to learn Ruby-on-Rails, and I'm finding that it's extremely idiomatic, and has a lot of what I consider to be magic going on behind the scenes.

Can someone recommend a site or book to get up to speed? All of the stuff I've seen online has been "Ruby for beginners" and I'm sure that those are great for their intended audiences, but I want something that tells me directly what I need to know to translate what I already know about every other programming language, into Rails idioms and conventions.

ETA:

So far I've read Why's Poignant guide to Ruby, and the Ruby on Rails Guides.

I'm noticing that everything is from the point of view of "Write your first app!!!"  Unfortunately that's not my situation. I have a large app that someone else already wrote that I need to maintain. That's a totally different way of looking at the problem. I don't need to know how to install and set up the thing. I DO need to know how to find where everything that's referenced lives. When you're writing a small 1st app, you know where everything lives, because you put it there 15 minutes ago....

So, does anyone know of a "How to read a large Ruby on Rails/ Coffeescript app that someone else wrote" document?